# How to display JSON object to TextView? Any advice would be tremendously appreciated

Tags: java, android, json

I want to display the titles of the retuned json data from newsapi to a textview. Is there a correct way of doing so? The titles of each article are returned, i know this because inside the for loop Log.i("Titles, title) outputs the required titles to the logcat. I just need to somehow convert them into textviews or any means that allows the user to view the titles. Kind regards,
Rob.

```
public class quotesPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String FactsUrl;
    Button goButton;
    TextView displayBox;
    String [] array;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes_page);



        goButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        displayBox = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FactsUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=health&apiKey=2b3d6472849543e4a908f43cf5c77410";
                //displayBox.setText("THIS IS JUST A TEST ");
                new quotesPage.AsyncHttpTask().execute(FactsUrl);
            }
        });

    }
    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL (urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                parseResult(response);
                return result;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String data;
        String result = "";

        while ((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result += data;
        }
        if (null != stream)
        {
            stream.close();
        }

        return result;

    }

    public void parseResult(String result)
    {
        JSONObject response = null;
        try {
            response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray articles = response.optJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject article = articles.optJSONObject(i);
                String title = article.optString("title");
                Log.i("Titles", title);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

activity_quotes_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    tools:context=".quotesPage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="445dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
            android:text="Click the GO! button to see uk health news headlines!"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
            android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
            android:text="Go!"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/leftarrowlarge" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/timerlarge" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rightarrowlarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What id like to do is in the "parseResult" for loop have this:

displayBox.append(displayBox + title);

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want a list of TextViews, each one showing one of the titles? Or do you want a single TextView with a list of Titles within it? I am assuming by your question that you actually want a list of TextViews.

Comment: Dear Hypino, either would be perfect. Preferably one text view showing all of the titles. Kind regards, Rob

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

The industry standard of making an api call and consume the json response is using retrofit, and get an object as the result.  Once you learn how to use it, you will never use asyntask and parse json yourself.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#retrofit) on how to do it.

Comment: Dear uDevel, thank you very much! I really appreciate it. So the code I've shown is useless then?

Comment: I am sorry.  But if you want to improve, I would suggest to go with the industry standard.  Although it's important to understand how parse the json and asyntasks, I remember I was doing that 5 or 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a Model for parsing and using network data easily.

```
public class ModelArticleList {
    List<ModelArticle> list;

    public List<ModelArticle> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void parseData(String s) {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray articles = jsonObject.optJSONArray("articles");
            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject article = articles.optJSONObject(i);
                ModelArticle modelArticle = new ModelArticle();
                modelArticle.parseData(article);
                list.add(modelArticle);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ModelArticle {

    String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    void parseData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        if(jsonObject != null) {
            title = jsonObject.optString("title");
        }
    }
}
```

Now use a list view or a recycler view depending on your needs to display the titles.